# Scientific formula food

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am reading *A Street Cat Named Bob* by James Bowen. Here's one paragraph from chapter 2:

That afternoon I headed to a local pet store and got him (my cat) a couple of weeks' worth of food. I'd been given a sample of **scientific formula food** at the RSPCA and tried it on him the previous night. He'd liked it so I bought a bag of that. I also got him a supply of cat food. It cost me around 9 pounds, which really was the last money I had.

What does "scientific formula food" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially prescription cat food, or a formula for life stages (more fat for kittens, less protein for old cats, more plant mass for indoor cats), differentiating it from generic cat food, and often with free samples at vets and shelters for marketing purposes.  The most common brand in the US and UK is [known as Science Diet or Science Plan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Diet) and the author may be making a deliberate demonstration that the narrator recognizes what it is without making a product placement in their book.

Answer (score -1):

Don't confuse "scientific" with "mathematical" or "physics" here, it's actually "biological". So this is food that has been made according to a formula that says what food should contain - x% protein, y% vitamins etc.

Comment: Without supporting evidence, 'scientific formula food' might be taken to be just advertising hype. Food containing more than zero amounts of protein, vitamins etc. Is the term legally defined? There are very few hits on Google.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm aware of that, but I didn't want to muddle the issue by giving my opinion either way in my answer. So I remained with defining the phrase for the OP.

Comment: So this gives the impression of being food that has been made according to a formula that says what food should contain - x% protein, y% vitamins etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OK, OK, I edited my answer. Better now?

Comment: If 'scientific formula food' is a compound or close collocation, there needs to be an authoritative reference to the way it is usually understood. If it's not, I consider the question to be POB as it stands.

Comment: By the way, pay attention to "I ALSO got him a supply of cat food", which means that that scientific formula food was not necessarily cat food... Next day he bought that "mysterious" food as well as some cat food... That's interesting... Can't cat food be scientific formula, that is "biological"? I think it can...

Comment: The name of this community is English Language and Usage. I have asked a question related to the usage of a specific phrase taken from a specific book. If it's wrong, what is this community for? I don't agree that the question is POB as it stands. I have given the source and the whole paragraph to provide the context. So how should the question stand? I'm sorry if my comment seems too emotional.